# find the sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 below 1000

Tags: java

Ok guys, so I'm doing the Project Euler challenges and I can't believe I'm stuck on the [first challenge](http://projecteuler.net/problem=1). I really can't see why I'm getting the wrong answer despite my code looking functional:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Multithree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> y = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int totalforthree = 0;
        int totalforfive = 0;

        int total =0;

        for(int temp =0; temp < 1000 ; temp++){
            if(temp % 3 == 0){
                x.add(temp);
                totalforthree += temp;
            }
        }

        for(int temp =0; temp < 1000 ; temp++){
            if(temp % 5 == 0){
                y.add(temp);
                totalforfive += temp;
            }
        }

        total = totalforfive + totalforthree;



        System.out.println("The multiples of 3 or 5 up to 1000 are: " +total);

    }

}
```

I'm getting the answer as 266333 and it says it's wrong...

Comment: You're double-counting `15`.

Comment: @SLaks And all its multiples

Comment: Instead of looping twice with one condition each, loop once with two conditions (connected with an "or").

Comment: "despite my code looking functional" In general functional just means it runs, doesn't mean it does remotely close to what you need it to.

Comment: maybe store the values in arrays and check for doubles before finalizing the answer.

Comment: The title says "AND" and the code says "OR" wich is the correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you should use the same for loop for both to aviod double counting numbers that are multiple of both. such as 15,30...

```
   for(int temp =0; temp < 1000 ; temp++){
        if(temp % 3 == 0){
            x.add(temp);
            totalforthree += temp;
        }else if(temp % 5 == 0){
            y.add(temp);
            totalforfive += temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The whole problem could be solved with just `int total = 0; for (int i=1; i<1000; ++i) { if (i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0) { total += i; } };`. There's really no need for separate accumulators for five and three, or the ArrayLists.

Answer (score 2):

In a mathematical perspective,

You did not consider about common factors between 3 and 5.
Because there is double counting.

ex; number 15 , 
30 , 
45 , 
60 , 
75 , 
90 , 
105 , 
120 , 
135 , 
150 , 
165 , 
180 , 
195 , 
210 , 
225 , 
240 , 
255 , 
270 , 
285 , 
300 , 
315 , 
330 , 
345 , 
360 , 
375 , 
390 , 
405 , 
420 , 
435 , 
450 , 
465 , 
480 , 
495 , 
510 , 
525 , 
540 , 
555 , 
570 , 
585 , 
600 , 
615 , 
630 , 
645 , 
660 , 
675 , 
690 , 
705 , 
720 , 
735 , 
750 , 
765 , 
780 , 
795 , 
810 , 
825 , 
840 , 
855 , 
870 , 
885 , 
900 , 
915 , 
930 , 
945 , 
960 , 
975 , 
990 , are common factors.

 total of common factors = 33165.

 Your answer is 266333

 Correct answer is 233168.

Your Answer - Total of common factors

 266333-33165=233168.

(this is a code for getting common factors and Total of common factors )

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("The sum of the Common Factors : " + getCommonFactorSum());

}

private static int getCommonFactorSum() {
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
        sum += i;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you all think instead of using loops to compute the sum of multiples, we can easily compute sum of n terms using a simple [formula of Arithmetic Progression to compute sum of n terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).

I evaluated results on both using loop and formula. Loops works simply valuable to short data ranges. But when the data ranges grows more than 10<sup>10</sup> program takes more than hours to process the result with loops. But the same evaluates the result in milliseconds when using a simple formula of Arithmetic Progression.

What we really need to do is:
**Algorithm :**

1. Compute the sum of multiples of 3 and add to sum.
2. Compute the sum of multiples of 5 and add to sum.
3. Compute the sum of multiples of 3*5 = 15 and subtract from sum.

Here is code snippet in java from my blog post [CodeForWin - Project Euler 1: Multiples of 3 and 5](http://codeforwin.blogspot.in/2015/06/project-euler-multiples-of-3-and-5.html)

```
n--; //Since we need to compute the sum less than n.
//Check if n is more than or equal to 3 then compute sum of all divisible by
//3 and add to sum.  
if(n>=3) {  
    totalElements = n/3;  
    sum += (totalElements * ( 3 + totalElements*3)) / 2;  
}  

//Check if n is more than or equal to 5 then compute sum of all elements   
//divisible by 5 and add to sum.  
if(n >= 5) {  
    totalElements = n/5;  
    sum += (totalElements * (5 + totalElements * 5)) / 2;  
}  

//Check if n is more than or equal to 15 then compute sum of all elements  
//divisible by 15 and subtract from sum.  
if(n >= 15) {  
    totalElements = n/15;  
    sum -= (totalElements * (15 + totalElements * 15)) / 2;  
}  

System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 you can do it in the following way:

```
Integer sum = IntStream.range(1, 1000) // create range
                  .filter(i -> i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) // filter out
                  .sum(); // output: 233168
```

To count the numbers which are divisible by both `3` and `5` twice you can 
either write the above line twice or `.map()` the `2 * i` values:

```
Integer sum = IntStream.range(1, 1000)
                  .filter(i -> i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
                  .map(i -> i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 ? 2 * i : i)
                  .sum(); // output: 266333
```

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this is that I took an integer value (initialized to zero) and kept on adding the incremented value of i, if its modulo with 3 or 5 gives me zero.

```
private static int getSum() {
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
        sum += i;
    }
}
return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this several ways and several times. The fastest, cleanest and simplest way to complete the required code for Java is this:

```
public class MultiplesOf3And5 {

public static void main(String[] args){

System.out.println("The sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 is: " + getSum());

}

private static int getSum() {
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
        sum += i;
    }
}
return sum;
}
```

If anyone has a suggestion to get it down to fewer lines of code, please let me know your solution.  I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000 / 3; i++)
{
count = count + (i * 3);
if (i < 1000 / 5 && !(i % 3 == 0))
{
count = count + (i * 5);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out the mistakes in your code, however I want to add that **the modulus operator solution is not the most *efficient***.

**A faster implementation** would be something like this:

```
int multiply3_5(int max)
{
  int i, x3 = 0, x5 = 0, x15 = 0;
    
  for(i = 3; i < max; i+=3)    x3 += i;    // Store all multiples of 3
  for(i = 5; i < max; i+=5)    x5 += i;    //  Store all multiples of 5
  for(i = 15; i < max; i+=15)  x15 += i;   //   Store all multiples 15; 
 
  return x3+x5-x15;
}
```

In this solution I had to take out multiples of 15 because, 3 and 5 have 15 as multiple so on the second loop it will add multiples of 15 that already been added in the first loop;

**Solution with a time complexity of `O(1)`**

Another even better solution (with a time complexity of `O(1)`) is if you take a mathematical approach.

You are trying to sum all numbers like this 3 + 6 + 9  ... 1000 and 5 + 10 + 15 +20 + ... 1000 this is the same of having 3 * (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + …  + 333)  and 5 * ( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + 200), the sum of 'n' natural number is (n * (n + 1)) ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)) so you can calculate in a constant time, as it follows:

```
int multiply3_5(int max)
{
   int x3 =   (max - 1) / 3; 
   int x5 =   (max - 1) / 5;
   int x15 =  (max - 1) / 15;                  
   int sn3 =  (x3 * (x3 + 1)) / 2; 
   int sn5 =  (x5 * (x5 + 1)) / 2; 
   int sn15 = (x15 * (x15 + 1)) / 2;
   return (3*sn3) + (5 *sn5) - (15*sn15);
}
```

**Running Example:**

```
public class SumMultiples2And5 {

    public static int multiply3_5_complexityN(int max){
        int i, x3 = 0, x5 = 0, x15 = 0;

        for(i = 3; i < max; i+=3)    x3 += i;    // Store all multiples of 3
        for(i = 5; i < max; i+=5)    x5 += i;    //  Store all multiples of 5
        for(i = 15; i < max; i+=15)  x15 += i;   //   Store all multiples 15;

        return x3 + x5 - x15;
    }

    public static int multiply3_5_constant(int max){
        int x3 =   (max - 1) / 3;
        int x5 =   (max - 1) / 5;
        int x15 =  (max - 1) / 15;
        int sn3 =  (x3 * (x3 + 1)) / 2;
        int sn5 =  (x5 * (x5 + 1)) / 2;
        int sn15 = (x15 * (x15 + 1)) / 2;
        return (3*sn3) + (5 *sn5) - (15*sn15);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(multiply3_5_complexityN(1000));
        System.out.println(multiply3_5_constant(1000));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
233168
233168
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=1;i<1000;i++){
            if(i%3==0 || i%5==0){
                sum+=i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are counting some numbers twice. What you have to do is add inside one for loop, and use an if-else statement where if you find multiples of 3, you do not count them in 5 as well.

```
 if(temp % 3 == 0){
     x.add(temp);
     totalforthree += temp;
 } else if(temp % 5 == 0){
     y.add(temp);
     totalforfive += temp;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Logics given above are showing wrong answer, because multiples of 3 & 5 are taken for calculation. There is something being missed in above logic, i.e., 15, 30, 45, 60... are the multiple of 3 and also multiple of 5. then we need to ignore such while adding.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int Sum=0, i=0, j=0;
    for(i=0;i<=1000;i++)
        if (i%3==0 && i<=999)
            Sum=Sum+i;
    for(j=0;j<=1000;j++)
        if (j%5==0 && j<1000 && j*5%3!=0)
            Sum=Sum+j;
    System.out.println("The Sum is "+Sum);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so this isn't the best looking code, but it get's the job done.

```
public class Multiples {

public static void main(String[]args) {
    int firstNumber = 3;
    int secondNumber = 5;
    ArrayList<Integer> numberToCheck = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> multiples = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int sumOfMultiples = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
       numberToCheck.add(i);

       if (numberToCheck.get(i) % firstNumber == 0 || numberToCheck.get(i) % secondNumber == 0) {
           multiples.add(numberToCheck.get(i));
       }

    }

    for (int i=0; i<multiples.size(); i++) {

     sumOfMultiples += multiples.get(i);

    }
    System.out.println(multiples);
    System.out.println("Sum Of Multiples: " + sumOfMultiples);

}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If number is 10 then multiple of 3 is 3,6,9 and multiple of 5 is 5,10 total sum is 33 and program gives same answer:

```
package com.parag;

/*
 * @author Parag Satav
 */
public class MultipleAddition {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> y = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int totalforthree = 0;
    int totalforfive = 0;
    int number = 8;

    int total = 0;

    for ( int temp = 1; temp <= number; temp++ ) {
        if ( temp % 3 == 0 ) {
            x.add( temp );
            totalforthree += temp;
        }

        else if ( temp % 5 == 0 ) {
            y.add( temp );
            totalforfive += temp;
        }
    }

    total = totalforfive + totalforthree;
    System.out.println( "multiples of 3 : " + x );
    System.out.println( "multiples of 5 : " + y );
    System.out.println( "The multiples of 3 or 5 up to " + number + " are: " + total );

}

}
```

Comment: if number is 10 then multiple of 3 is 3,6,9 and multiple of 5 is 5,10 total sum is 33 and program gives same answer you can check it

Comment: I recommend putting that in the body of your text.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while (t>0){
            int sum = 0;
            int count =0;
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            n--; 
            System.out.println((n/3*(6+(n/3-1)*3))/2 + (n/5*(10+(n/5-1)*5))/2 - (n/15*(30+(n/15-1)*15))/2);
            t--;
    }
}
}
```